# rosdep error view is empty

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to go though this tutorial:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

I managed to successfully create the packages, however when I try and run

```
rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials
```

Then I got this error:

```
[rospack] Error: the rosdep view is empty: call 'sudo rosdep init' and 'rosdep update'
```

After doing both of those things nothing seems to be working. Does anyone know how to go about fixing this? It presents the error no matter what packages I try the command on.

Update:

That's got it. Thanks for the assistance. I'll update my answers in the future, thanks for reminding me!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65650/rosdep-error-view-is-empty/) by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 124 on 2013-06-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have likely skipped parts of the installation instructions: especially 1.5 of http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu#Initialize_rosdep

If you have executed the two command to initialize and update rosdep what was the output? Did they failed?

Update:

As your output shows you are calling "rosdep update" with sudo which makes it generate the rosdep database in the home folder of the user root and not in the home folder of your actual user.
Just run "rosdep update" (without root) as suggested by the original error message and it should work.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-06-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) on 2013-06-22**:
I didn't miss that step while I was installing. Initializing and updating have never returned errors for me.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-06-23**:
Can you post the output of the commands? And the content of the file `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list` as well as the listing of the folder `~/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/`.

**Comment by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) on 2013-06-24**:
See the answer below, the output was too long for a comment.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-06-24**:
Please update your question in the future and not post it as an answer.

**Comment by [meropis](https://answers.ros.org/users/121372/meropis/) on 2022-10-21**:
Running rosdep update removed my entire ros install.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the data you asked for:

```
vboxuser@debian:~$ sudo rm /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list 
vboxuser@debian:~$ sudo rosdep init
Wrote /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Recommended: please run

    rosdep update

vboxuser@debian:~$ sudo rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Ignore legacy gbpdistro "groovy"
Ignore legacy gbpdistro "hydro"
Query rosdistro index https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml
Add distro "groovy"
Add distro "hydro"
updated cache in /root/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
vboxuser@debian:~$ cat /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
# os-specific listings first
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml gentoo

# generic
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
gbpdistro https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml fuerte
gbpdistro https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/groovy.yaml groovy
gbpdistro https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/hydro.yaml hydro
vboxuser@debian:~$ cat ~/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/
cat: /home/vboxuser/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/: No such file or directory
```

---

Originally posted by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) with karma: 124 on 2013-06-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-24**:
Please edit your question to add more information.